# Boot loop after uninstalling Ubuntu from dual boot with Windows 11

Tags: ubuntu, boot, uefi, windows-11

My case is GPT scheme and UEFI system, Xiaomi Redmibook 14 laptop. I was having dual boot Windows 11 + Ubuntu 22.04 and decided to uninstall Ubuntu (it was installed with Rufus, selected GPT and UEFI). I deleted Ubuntu partitions through Disk management in Windows. After that, while trying to turn or reboot my device I started having a boot loop with message “reset system” (screenshot [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKSqo.jpg)). Fortunately, I still can boot into Windows 11, if I hold F2 button, enter UEFI and exit it.

[image]

My goal is to boot into Windows automatically without entering UEFI and not doing any hard resets. Reinstalling Ubuntu could fix this issue, but I don't need it.

I've tried but it didn't help:

- Deleted grub through command line with `diskpart` (EFI folder) and `bcdedit`
- Checking boot order in UEFI (there is only Windows Boot Manager, nothing else)
- Checking if I have Boot order Lock in UEFI (it doesn’t even have this option)
- Disabling/enabling secure boot AND fast boot
- “bootrec.exe /fixmbr” in Windows command line
- Checking Boot Repair Tool through Ubuntu USB flash drive (it didn’t suggest repair)
- *Re-create/repair boot files* option in EasyBCD software
- Looking for *Select an UEFI file…* option (I don’t have it in UEFI)
- Looking for *Legacy support* option (also no option in UEFI)

bcdedit output:

[image: screenshot]

In regedit HarddiskVolume2 is listed as a system partition.
Also I checked volumes in WinObj, seems to be that HarddiskVolume4 is a boot partition

WinObj:

[image: screenshot from WinObj]

Considering my bcdedit output, maybe I should type this in cmd?

Code below:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: I do not know how to get out of this without a Reset.  If you do choose to use Reset you should be able to Keep Data (which keeps your user profile). This makes installing apps fairly quick and easy.  If you do this, then you really should be using Virtual Machines to test other systems.  This will not risk your Windows 11 system or be unsafe.

Comment: Provide your BCD verbose output (bcdedit /enum /v)

Comment: @OP - What have you done.

Comment: So it appears the EFI partition is mapped to HarddiskVolume2, from what you can tell based on your system configuration, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

This command helped fixing Windows boot:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).